# Animate deleted data on refresh in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a mobile app built using React Native. I'm using a pubsub library to make my app real time. I have a fantasy football team, which multiple people can modify. When one user deletes a player from a list, it sends a message to all other users to refresh their list. However, when their list is refreshed, the new information just overrides the old information (with setState) and the deleted player just disappears very fast. How can I instead make all the differences in the information (deleted players) fade out or some other animation. I'm not as concerned about the animation part as i am concerned about pinpointing the differences in current state and fetched data, and then fading out the data that is in current state but not in fetched data.

Comment: It’s not  a problem that I’m having, it’s more of a feature I want to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `react-native`'s `LayoutAnimation` library. It will automatically find out the items that were deleted (or added) to your state and you can pass the property you want animate. But with this easiness some drawbacks also come! You can find demo code [here.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation) If you want advanced and more configurable solution `react-native-reanimated` is the best! It comes with `transition` animations which are useful for your case! [Here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated) it's full documentation.